# What is wrong with this getElementsByClassName call in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access the width of a div to put in a cookie. This is the div:

```
 <div class="tab_panel" style="width:600px">
```

It is the only div with this class name. It is not an option to specify a unique id for the div. This is the code I have been using in an event to call it but it gives an error:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName(tab_panel).style.width
```

I know Firefox supports `getElementsByClassName`, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14):

It's a string:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("tab_panel")[0].style.width
```

Bye

P.S. It's an array

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementsByClassName("tab_panel")` returns a collection of nodes, the first of which is referred to by `document.getElementsByClassName("tab_panel")[0]`.

If the node you are searching does not have an inline style="width:' assignment, an empty string is returned from `document.getElementsByClassName("tab_panel")[0].style.width`.

Answer (score 2):

Missing ***quotes***:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('tab_panel').....
```

You should iterate over all elements like this:

```
var elms = document.getElementsByClassName('tab_panel');

for(var i = 0 ; i < elms.length; i++)
{
   alert(elms[i].style.width);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try saying:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("tab_panel")
```