# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientHeight' of null

Tags: javascript

I don't know why it can't find the height. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var h = document.getElementById('big_button').clientHeight,
    center = -h / 2;
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('big_button_container2').style.marginTop = 'center';
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4zux6/

Comment: You have no element with the ID `big_button`.

Comment: Needs semicolon `;` after clientHeight instead of comma `,` ?

Comment: @JohnMcMahon: The `,` is correct. It's declaring multiple variables.

Comment: @cookiemonster can't believe I missed that, I must be quite tired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use document.getElementsByClass instead as you have only elements with class names not IDs.

i.e.

```
var h = document.getElementsByClassName('big_button')[0].clientHeight,
    center = -h / 2;
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementsByClassName('big_button_container2')[0].style.marginTop = 'center';
};
```

Comment: You need to access individual elements from the returned collection. I don't know which one is meant to be targeted, but the first would be at index `0`.

Comment: Now I'm getting this _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'marginTop' of undefined_. How is center undefined?

Comment: @dillonbrannick I forgot that that give you an array of elements with that class name. So you have to access the element you want at index 0. I changed the answer to reflect that. Does at work? Alternatively just add IDs to the elements you want to access and use your previous method of getElementById.

Comment: Note that if you have more than one element with the same class name you would have to iterate through them like in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14142710/3208425).