# tried to change the inner element of dynamic div through class name but its not working

Tags: javascript

I have create the dynamic div and now trying to change the inner html of it but its not working please help me here is the code

```
function like(id)
{
var orgnldiv=document.getElementById(id);
var ndiv=document.createElement('DIV');
ndiv.id = 'like';
ndiv.className="likeclass";
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("likeclass");
orgnldiv.appendChild(ndiv); 
classname.innerHTML="example";
//alert(id);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
function like(id)
{
    var orgnldiv=document.getElementById(id);
    var ndiv=document.createElement('DIV');
    ndiv.id = 'like';
    ndiv.className="likeclass";
    orgnldiv.appendChild(ndiv); 
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("likeclass");
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].innerHTML="example";
    }
}
```

You get error because `getElementsByClassName` returns array of elements, not one elements. So you have to work with result like with array. If 1 element return loop will fire only 1 time. If 0 elements it wouldn't fire.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 3):

Beware of the **s** in Elements. That means that you are getting a list rather than a single control.

Check [How to use getElementsByClassName in javascript-function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142677/how-to-use-getelementsbyclassname-in-javascript-function)

Comment: yes i know about s in elements i want to change inner html of all the dive's which have same class

Comment: You need a loop do go through all controls in the resulting list

Comment: @AyyanAlvi Ted gave link, where you can find explanation how to do this. Just try to open it and try something by yourself.