# How to go from getElementByID to getElementsByClassName when creating multible select elements?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I have multiple select elements that I need to get the same options using Javascript. They all have the same class. This code works with an id but not with class.

I tried changing getElementById to getElementsByClassName, but that doesn't seem to work. I am pretty new to Javascript and don't completely understand the difference between these two commands.

The code:

```
<select class="phoneNumber"></select>
<script>
phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber");

var option = document.createElement('option'); option.text = '1234567897'; phoneNumber.appendChild(option);
var option = document.createElement('option'); option.text = '1233213211'; phoneNumber.appendChild(option);
</script>
```

Comment: **getElementById** will return you a single element where as **getElementsByClassName** will return array of all element with the same class.

Comment: Yes, but how do i get getElementsByClassName to work in that code? I need to replicate the select options in all selects with the class phoneNumber and it simply doesn't work changing it to getElementsByClassName. Do you have a solution to my problem K.D?

Answer (score 0):

Using querySelector instead of getElementsByClassName solved this problem.

Comment: How does `.querySelector()` solve the problem? It will only return the first element found by the selector

Comment: I realized that now after some more testing. Do you have a solution to this problem  Andreas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-does-getelementsbyclassname-return

Comment: That is probably the right answer but I did not get it to work. Could you be kind and help me by changing my code to the correct answer? That way I'll also understand it better.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142677/how-to-use-getelementsbyclassname-in-javascript-function