# Date and Time is not displayed by getElementsByClassName function

Tags: javascript

I know that it can be achieved by getElementById function also, but i want use getElementsByClassName function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <h1>Date And Time</h1>

        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementByClassName('demo').innerHTML=Date()">Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

        <p id="demo"></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

I am biggner in Java, So please help me.... thank You

Comment: For starters, java != javascript

Comment: See if this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142677/how-to-use-getelementsbyclassname-in-javascript-function

Comment: Also, your `<p>` tag as demo as an id, not as a class.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is `javascript` not `java`. Now your problem is you are accessing `p` tag with class name but that `p` tag doesn't have a class so,

Replace

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

with

```
<p class="demo"></p>
```

Comment: may also be worth noting that `document.getElementByClassName` should be `document.getElementsByClassName` which returns an array so it will need to be `document.getElementsByClassName('demo')[0].innerHTML=Date()`

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName() returns a node list. `[0]` gets the first.

```
    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('demo')[0].innerHTML='Hello'">Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

    <p class="demo"></p>
```